# As of IOS 7 is there a way to access the phone number dialled?

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I'm not very informed on ios news, but I've looked everywhere the last few days and can't seem to find a definitive answer for the latest version of ios: Is it possible to retrieve a list (or simply the last) phone number dialled? The docs (coretelephony) mention a CallID but I'm guessing that the most you could do with that is distinguish between two different calls. I've noticed many blog posts/stackoverflow questions mentioning accessing a call log database, however from my own tests and from what I've gathered that no longer works in the latest versions of ios (infact all of the posts are dated at least two years ago). Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean it no longer works?  Do you get thrown exceptions?  Compilation error?  You have to be more specific.  What have you tried?  Give us some code.

Comment: @evan.stoddard, sandbox rules no longer allowes you to access it.

Comment: @creker Gotcha.  I just figured I'd ask.  One, maybe there was a chance I could help.  Two, to let him know that in the future he needs to give more details.  Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @alexvlasov, you can access phone number only using Private API. Even on non-jailbroken device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no access to phone numbers or dialing, due to security reasons. But, you can get info on the connected Carrier, etc.

Comment: That's what I've gathered, thank you for the definitive answer though